# How do I wrap some PHP code with a link?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I'm quite new to PHP and am having issues inserting a link into some of my code in the `echo` statement.

Thie following is what I have so far...

```
<div class="cta">
    <?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
        echo '<a href="/create-an-account/">Create Account</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp; 
              <a href="/login">Login</a>';
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome,&nbsp;' . $current_user->display_name;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

I want to wrap `$current_user->display_name` with a link but every time I attempt this, the whole page breaks.

Obviously my syntax is wrong but being new to PHP I am not certain how to fix this issue.

Comment: Try showing us what you tried, that way we can help you pointing you to **what** you did wrong and **why** rather than just giving you the correct solution. That's a better way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your else block

```
echo 'Welcome, <a href="/your-url-here">' . $current_user->display_name . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance with my issue, Captain Hypertext.

Answer (score 1):

You Can just use concatenation as you are already with your example.

You can edit it with the below:

```
<div class="cta">
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    echo '<a href="/create-an-account/">Create Account</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp; 
          <a href="/login">Login</a>';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, <a href="ThisisYourLink">' . $current_user->display_name .'</a>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance with my issue, Aaron K.

Comment: My Pleasure, @davebrener . Good Luck!